# ¿Como detecto cierto grado de opacidad en un GameObject? Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

estoy haciendo un laser para mi juego y quiero hacer que cuando su sprite llegue a 230 de opacidad haga daño. Tengo hecha una animacion que va de 0 a 230 y devuelta a 0. Me servirìa la ayuda para hacer daño con mi laser gracias.[image: esta es el grado maximo de opacidad de mi animación]

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un [example], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías estar constantemente verificando que la opacidad sea la esperada pero hay una mejor opción en este caso.

En Unity puedes agregar eventos a las animaciones, dando clic al botón del un cuadrado blanco o haciendo doble clic en la sección de la derecha en la posición que quieras que esté.

[image: https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/AnimationEditorEventLine.png]

Cuando la animación llegue al punto del evento, se llamará una función de un script con unos parámetros. Todo esto lo debes configurar dando clic al evento.

[image: https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/AnimationEventInspector.png]

Más información:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html

Comment: Osea que le agrego un evento entre los segundos que quiero que haga daño mi laser, y luego creo una funcion para ese evento en un script que  haga daño al player? No me queda claro la parte de la funcion ¿Como hago para que haga daño? ¿Y como lo relaciono al script de la vida del personaje que es el que quita los corazones?

Comment: Está más o menos claro. Haces una función con el nombre que gustes y la elijes ahí en el evento. En esa función pones el código correspondiente para que haga daño o lo que necesites. Por cierto, esas últimas 2 preguntas quedan fuera de tu pregunta original, que era sobre la opacidad.